# Differences between real redis and Heroku redis add-ons

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

Running the shown-at-the-end piece of code on Heroku I see major differences to the program behavior depending on whether I use my redis server or a heroku redis add-on (tried both RedisCloud and RedisToGo unsuccessfully).

The test code is a Redis PubSub to websockets emitter via primus rooms.

I'll start by showing the expected program behaviour.

I have the REDISLOCAL_URL environment variable pointing to my own redis server running redis 2.8.6 (the same version as RedisCloud)

In the logs I see:

```
{"name":"index","hostname":"04580326-9e33-4829-bf89-301e10f85fe7","pid":2,"level":30,"msg":"Server running on port 19690","time":"2014-04-27T16:38:38.706Z","v":0}
{"name":"index","hostname":"04580326-9e33-4829-bf89-301e10f85fe7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Redis Sub ready on ckir.homeip.net","time":"2014-04-27T16:38:39.226Z","v":0}
{"name":"index","hostname":"04580326-9e33-4829-bf89-301e10f85fe7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Redis Pub ready on ckir.homeip.net","time":"2014-04-27T16:38:39.225Z","v":0}
{"name":"index","hostname":"04580326-9e33-4829-bf89-301e10f85fe7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Redis Pub authenticated","time":"2014-04-27T16:38:39.224Z","v":0}
{"name":"index","hostname":"04580326-9e33-4829-bf89-301e10f85fe7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Redis Sub authenticated","time":"2014-04-27T16:38:39.226Z","v":0}
```

At this point I connect a client (external browser). Everything is fine and I can see the time ticking on my browser.

```
{"name":"index","hostname":"04580326-9e33-4829-bf89-301e10f85fe7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Client connected id: 1398617743234$0","time":"2014-04-27T16:55:43.236Z","v":0}
{"name":"index","hostname":"04580326-9e33-4829-bf89-301e10f85fe7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Client subscribed to time, 1 total subscriptions","time":"2014-04-27T16:55:43.595Z","v":0}
```

At this point I press reload on my browser. The program as expected disconnects and unsubscribes and then reconnects and subscribes again. No matter how many times I press reload the behaviour remains the same.

```
{"name":"index","hostname":"04580326-9e33-4829-bf89-301e10f85fe7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Client disconnected id: 1398617743234$0","time":"2014-04-27T16:56:06.995Z","v":0}
{"name":"index","hostname":"04580326-9e33-4829-bf89-301e10f85fe7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Client unsubscribed from time, 0 total subscriptions","time":"2014-04-27T16:56:07.160Z","v":0}
{"name":"index","hostname":"04580326-9e33-4829-bf89-301e10f85fe7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Client connected id: 1398617768295$1","time":"2014-04-27T16:56:08.298Z","v":0}
{"name":"index","hostname":"04580326-9e33-4829-bf89-301e10f85fe7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Client subscribed to time, 1 total subscriptions","time":"2014-04-27T16:56:08.630Z","v":0}
```

At this point I close my browser so no reconnection occurs.

```
{"name":"index","hostname":"04580326-9e33-4829-bf89-301e10f85fe7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Client disconnected id: 1398617768295$1","time":"2014-04-27T16:56:31.229Z","v":0}
{"name":"index","hostname":"04580326-9e33-4829-bf89-301e10f85fe7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Client unsubscribed from time, 0 total subscriptions","time":"2014-04-27T16:56:31.393Z","v":0}
```

At this point I enter a "heroku config unset REDISLOCAL_URL" so heroku restarts the dyno and I see.

```
Redis connections closed
```

I'm going to repeat the above steps using RedisCloud this time.

We start well. The connection is fine.

```
{"name":"index","hostname":"97617fd4-4224-4c3f-a638-3b9f6840fdb7","pid":2,"level":30,"msg":"Server running on port 35323","time":"2014-04-27T16:57:17.215Z","v":0}
{"name":"index","hostname":"97617fd4-4224-4c3f-a638-3b9f6840fdb7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Redis Sub ready on pub-redis-10891.us-east-1-2.1.ec2.garantiadata.com","time":"2014-04-27T16:57:17.242Z","v":0}
{"name":"index","hostname":"97617fd4-4224-4c3f-a638-3b9f6840fdb7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Redis Pub ready on pub-redis-10891.us-east-1-2.1.ec2.garantiadata.com","time":"2014-04-27T16:57:17.243Z","v":0}
{"name":"index","hostname":"97617fd4-4224-4c3f-a638-3b9f6840fdb7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Redis Sub authenticated","time":"2014-04-27T16:57:17.237Z","v":0}
{"name":"index","hostname":"97617fd4-4224-4c3f-a638-3b9f6840fdb7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Redis Pub authenticated","time":"2014-04-27T16:57:17.242Z","v":0}
```

At this point I connect a client (external browser). Everything is fine and I can see the time ticking on my browser.

```
{"name":"index","hostname":"97617fd4-4224-4c3f-a638-3b9f6840fdb7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Client connected id: 1398617858982$0","time":"2014-04-27T16:57:38.985Z","v":0}
{"name":"index","hostname":"97617fd4-4224-4c3f-a638-3b9f6840fdb7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Client subscribed to time, 1 total subscriptions","time":"2014-04-27T16:57:39.150Z","v":0}
```

I press reload on my browser and here is the problem. No more reconnects and resubscribes anymore and no more data coming to the browser screen.

```
{"name":"index","hostname":"97617fd4-4224-4c3f-a638-3b9f6840fdb7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Client disconnected id: 1398617858982$0","time":"2014-04-27T16:57:58.560Z","v":0}
{"name":"index","hostname":"97617fd4-4224-4c3f-a638-3b9f6840fdb7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Client unsubscribed from time, 0 total subscriptions","time":"2014-04-27T16:57:58.561Z","v":0}
{"name":"index","hostname":"97617fd4-4224-4c3f-a638-3b9f6840fdb7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Client connected id: 1398617879988$1","time":"2014-04-27T16:57:59.989Z","v":0}
{"name":"index","hostname":"97617fd4-4224-4c3f-a638-3b9f6840fdb7","pid":2,"level":20,"msg":"Client disconnected id: 1398617879988$1","time":"2014-04-27T16:58:13.798Z","v":0}
```

I need to restart the dyno to make the browser client working again. Any ideas why this happens? Any possible workarounds?

Bellow is the code I use along with my package.json file for better documentation.

```
'use strict';
//
// Program exit handlers to close redis connections
//
var Sync = require('sync');
process.stdin.resume(); //so the program will not close instantly

function connectionsclose() {
    redisPub.end();
    redisSub.end();
    console.log("Redis connections closed");
    process.exit();
}

function exitHandler(options, err) {
    if (options.cleanup) {
        Sync(function() {
            connectionsclose();
        });
    }
    if (err) {
        Sync(function() {
            connectionsclose();
        });
    }
    if (options.exit) {
        process.exit();
    };
}

//do something when app is closing
process.on('exit', exitHandler.bind(null, {
    exit: true
}));

//catches ctrl+c event
process.on('SIGINT', exitHandler.bind(null, {
    cleanup: true
}));
process.on('SIGTERM', exitHandler.bind(null, {
    cleanup: true
}));

//catches uncaught exceptions
process.on('uncaughtException', exitHandler.bind(null, {
    cleanup: true
}));

//
// Start logging
//
var path = require('path');
var bunyan = require('bunyan');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var basename = path.basename(__filename, '.js');
var log = bunyan.createLogger({
    name: basename,
    streams: [{
        level: 'debug',
        stream: process.stdout
    }, {
        level: 'info',
        path: path.resolve('./logs/' + basename + '.log'),
    }]
});

//
// Do your express magic.
//
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', port);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/keepalive', function(req, res) {
    res.send('OK');
});

//
// Create Primus server
//
var http = require('http');
var Primus = require('primus');

var server = http.createServer(app);

var primus = new Primus(server, {
    transformer: 'websockets',
    parser: 'JSON',
});

primus.save(__dirname + '/public/primus.js');

primus.on('connection', function(spark) {

    log.debug("Client connected id: " + spark.id);

    spark.on('data', function(data) {
        data = data || {};
        log.trace("Client id: " + spark.id + " message: " + JSON.stringify(data));

        switch (data.command) {
            case 'join':
                redisSub.subscribe(data.room);
                break;
            case 'leave':
                redisSub.unsubscribe(data.room);
                break;
            default:
                log.debug("Client " + spark.id + " wrote " + JSON.stringify(message));
        }

    });

});

primus.on('disconnection', function(spark) {
    log.debug("Client disconnected id: " + spark.id);
    // unsubscribe from all the previously subscribed channels
    redisSub.unsubscribe();
});

server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    log.info('Server running on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

//
// Connect to redis  server
//
//For localhost password at /etc/redis/redis.conf at requirepass
var redis = require('redis');
//redis.debug_mode = true;

var url = require('url');

if (typeof process.env.REDISLOCAL_URL !== "undefined") {
    var redisURL = url.parse(process.env.REDISLOCAL_URL);
} else {
    var redisURL = url.parse(process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL);
}

var redisPub = redis.createClient(redisURL.port, redisURL.hostname, {
    no_ready_check: true
});
redisPub.auth(redisURL.auth.split(":")[1], function() {
    log.debug("Redis Pub authenticated");
});
redisPub.on("ready", function(err) {
    log.debug("Redis Pub ready on " + redisURL.hostname);
});
redisPub.on("error", function(err) {
    log.error("Redis Error " + err);
});
redisPub.on("end", function() {
    log.error("Redis Pub connection closed ");
});

var redisSub = redis.createClient(redisURL.port, redisURL.hostname, {
    no_ready_check: true
});
redisSub.auth(redisURL.auth.split(":")[1], function() {
    log.debug("Redis Sub authenticated");
});
redisSub.on("ready", function() {
    log.debug("Redis Sub ready on " + redisURL.hostname);
});

redisSub.on("error", function(err) {
    log.error("Redis Error " + err);
});

redisSub.on("subscribe", function(channel, count) {
    log.debug("Client subscribed to " + channel + ", " + count + " total subscriptions");
});

redisSub.on("unsubscribe", function(channel, count) {
    log.debug("Client unsubscribed from " + channel + ", " + count + " total subscriptions");
});

redisSub.on("message", function(channel, message) {
    log.trace("Client channel " + channel + ": " + message);
    primus.write({
        room: channel,
        msg: message
    });
});

redisSub.on("end", function() {
    log.error("Redis Sub connection closed ");
});

// A time channel for debugging
setInterval(function() {
    redisPub.publish('time', new Date().toISOString(), function() {});
}, 5000);
```

This is package.json

```
{
  "name": "rtnetsrvredis",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Connect a Redis PubSub channel to a primus room",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "CK",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "bunyan": "^0.22.3",
    "express": "^4.1.0",
    "hiredis": "^0.1.16",
    "primus": "^2.2.0",
    "redis": "^0.10.1",
    "sync": "^0.2.2",
    "ws": "^0.4.31"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the log have any relevant info? My Node.js fu is sub par, but is it possible that by reloading you're not closing the  connections and thus are reaching the plan's limit (I'm assuming you're using our [Redis Cloud] free plan for testing purposes)?

Comment: You are right. I use the free plan but the problem is not the number of open connections. I have noticed that heroku is not closing the open connections when destroys a dyno (e.g. after a push) and I have added the first part in my code to do that. The log file shows the sequence of events but you have to read it in conjuction with the code.

Comment: Understood - I'd appreciate your help in reproducing this so I can have a more thorough look into the matter - can you shoot me an email (itamar at redislabs.com) or a tweet (@itamarhaber) so we can pick this up?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have uploaded everything on github (https://github.com/ckir/redis-problem) and I will email you as well.